# angular input[datetime-local] not allowing PM times in Ionic app on Android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, datetimepicker

I've got an Ionic app with a datetime-local input which has been working forever, but now it seems the native Android selector that pops up does not allow the user to switch the "AM" to "PM".  I made no changes to the actual HTML or JS which would have broken this, so I'm guessing it's somewhere in Angular, Ionic, or Cordova.

EDIT: I tried making a datetime-local field with a *new* Ionic app like so:

```
ionic start throwaway
cd throwaway
```

Then I edited the 'tab-dash.html' file with the HTML below

Then...

```
ionic platform add android
ionic run android
```

...to run the app on my phone (Nexus 6 with Android 5.1.1).  It *still* won't let me change the "AM" to a "PM".  So I can definitely rule out my own code.

End EDIT.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="item item-input item-stacked-label" ng-class="{ 'has-errors' : error || thing.start && !thingPreview.isFuture(thing.start) }">
  <i class="icon ion-clock balanced"></i>
  <strong class="input-label">Start</strong>
  <input name="start" type="datetime-local" ng-model="thing.start" />
</div>
```

Again, this is only a problem on Android; it works fine on iOS.  I can't figure out where the selector is being rendered, so if you have any idea how to even begin debugging this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you have this issue on all Android devices ? What are the versions of Android ?

Comment: The issue is happening on my Nexus 6 with Android 5.1.1, but it is not happening on at least one older phone (Galaxy S3 with Android 4.4.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relic of old android days....2.3-4x

open platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml

and look/remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"`